# ConTeXt: Is ist possible to use matrices nested like in 'block' matrices?

Tags: math-mode, context, matrices

I tried to use context's `\startmatrix`/`\stopmatrix` nested with predefined matrix blocks. In latex it works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\matOne{\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}}
\def\matTwo{\begin{matrix}a\\b\end{matrix}}
\def\matThree{\begin{matrix}c & d\end{matrix}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \matOne & \matTwo\\
            \matThree & e\\
        \end{pmatrix}\\
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 0 & a\\
            0 & 1 & b\\
            c & d & e\\
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The top matrix out of blocks looks the same as the bottom one. In context I tried the following:

```
\definemathmatrix[pmatrix][left={\left(}, right={\right)}, distance=1em]

\def\matOne{\startmatrix\NC 1 \NC 0 \NR\NC 0 \NC 1\NR\stopmatrix}
\def\matTwo{\startmatrix\NC a\NR\NC b\NR\stopmatrix}
\def\matThree{\startmatrix\NC c \NC d\NR\stopmatrix}

\starttext

\startformula
    \startpmatrix
        \NC \matOne \NC \matTwo\NR
        \NC \matThree \NC e\NR
    \stoppmatrix
\stopformula
\startformula
    \startpmatrix
        \NC 1 \NC 0 \NC a \NR
        \NC 0 \NC 1 \NC b \NR
        \NC c \NC d \NC e\NR
    \stoppmatrix
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

Here the top matrix looks different than the bottom one. It seems that the distance isn't applied after a block matrix. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure whether this breaks something else but it seems as if the definition of `\NC` is not reverted properly.  Reported here: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089631.html

I cranked `distance` up to `2em` to make the difference more visible.

```
\unprotect

\def\math_matrix_stop
  {\crcr
 % \ifgridsnapping \else
     \mathstrut\crcr
     \noalign{\vskip-\baselineskip}%
 % \fi
   \egroup
   \gdef\math_matrix_NC{\endmath\aligntab}
   \egroup
   \mathmatrixright
   \endgroup}

\protect

\definemathmatrix[pmatrix][left={\left(}, right={\right)}, distance=2em]

\def\matOne{\startmatrix\NC 1 \NC 0 \NR\NC 0 \NC 1\NR\stopmatrix}
\def\matTwo{\startmatrix\NC a\NR\NC b\NR\stopmatrix}
\def\matThree{\startmatrix\NC c \NC d\NR\stopmatrix}

\starttext

\startformula
  \startpmatrix
    \NC \matOne \NC \matTwo \NC \matTwo \NR
    \NC \matThree \NC e \NC e\NR
  \stoppmatrix
\stopformula
\startformula
  \startpmatrix
    \NC 1 \NC 0 \NC a \NR
    \NC 0 \NC 1 \NC b \NR
    \NC c \NC d \NC e\NR
  \stoppmatrix
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Henry, so it seems like this is a bug in context. Your fix works in this case, but if a add a fourth column with another `\mathTwo` in the first row and an `f` in the second it doesn't work anymore. If you keep adding some columns it adds the distance only every second column.

Comment: @Icxolu Maybe it works now, maybe I broke something else this time...

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found any issue, so I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, nested matrices work currently with the current version of ConTeXt (2019.03.21). The bug was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/commit/6b89257547b260e08e805816ef752a4b5018328e). The code listed in the example gives the following:

[image]